# Can we use as.factor to convert categorical variables having multiple levels for decision tree or we need to use model.matrix please help!

Tags: r, cart, categorical-encoding

I am trying to build a decison tree model in R having both categorical and numerical variables.Some categorical variables have 3 levels , so can I just use as.factor and then use in my model? I tried to use model.matrix but my doubt is model.matrix converts the variable in numeric values of 0s and 1s and splitting happens on basis of these numeric values. For eg if Color has 3 level- blue,red,green, the splitting rule will look like color_green < 0.5 instead it should always take 0s and 1s only.

Comment: How are you implementing the cart model? If you use a library `rpart` or `caret` you just need to define the categorical variables as factors.

Comment: Okay I am using the caret package to implement the model

Comment: In that case you can define the categorical variables as factors. The function will take care about the conversion into dummy variables.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange!